# jquery make that color stay if active

Tags: jquery, colors, hover, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

An accordian style show/hide navigation system on five elements to reveal content and hide it onclick. Each of the five elements fades to a different color onhover.

Need to prevent the onmouseout color return animation if the element is the active element e.g. if it's child div is visible.

You can see the example here: 
http://dinosaurus.com.au/clients/theparrot/ with links to all scripts.

In summary: the active element should have the onmouseout effect removed so that the active color stays and does NOT return to its original state.

The foundations of the fade are here using David Walsh's dwFadingLinks function:

```
jQuery.fn.dwFadingLinks = function(settings) {
settings = jQuery.extend({
    color: '#ff8c00',
    duration: 500
}, settings);
    return this.each(function() {
        var original = $(this).css('color');
        $(this).mouseover(function() { $(this).animate({ color: settings.color },settings.duration); });
        $(this).mouseout(function() { $(this).animate({ color: original },settings.duration); });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#blue').dwFadingLinks({
    color: '#36F',
    duration: 500
});
$('#orange').dwFadingLinks({
    color: '#F90',
    duration: 500
});
$('#pink').dwFadingLinks({
    color: '#F09',
    duration: 500
});
$('#dkblue').dwFadingLinks({
    color: '#06C',
    duration: 500
});
$('#green').dwFadingLinks({
    color: '#093',
    duration: 500
});
 });
```

The show/hide script does not use jquery Accordion, rather this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.demo-show h3').add('div.demo-show2 h3').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
  $('div.demo-show h3').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.demo-show> div').hide();  
  $('div.demo-show> h3').click(function() {
    $('div.demo-show> h3').removeClass('active');
    $('div.demo-show> h3').removeClass('hover');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
    var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

    if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
      $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
        $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
      });
    } else {
       $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
    }
  });
});
```